# Function remove is removing the words too, not only the highlight

Tags: javascript

I have a function to highlight text.
So when select it highlight and when click it delete the highlight.

The problem is when delete it is removing not only the tag, but the word too.

Any ideas?

```js
// Select all elements on the page
let elements = document.querySelectorAll("*");

// Add event listeners for when user selects text on any element
elements.forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener("mouseup", highlightText);
  element.addEventListener("touchend", highlightText);
});

function highlightText() {
  let selection = window.getSelection().toString();

  if (selection !== '') {
    let range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    let newNode = document.createElement("mark");
    range.surroundContents(newNode);
}
}

// Add event listeners for when user clicks on highlighted text on any element
elements.forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (event.target.tagName === "MARK") {
      let mark = event.target;
      let textNode = mark.firstChild;
      mark.parentNode.insertBefore(textNode, mark);
      mark.parentNode.removeChild(mark);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the `remove` method and add the click listener to `highlightText` method

```
newNode.addEventListener('click', removeMarkedText);
```

**Snippet**

```js
// Select all elements on the page
const body = document.body

const highlightText = () => {
  const selection = window.getSelection().toString();

  if (selection !== '') {
    const range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    const newNode = document.createElement('mark');
    range.surroundContents(newNode);
    newNode.addEventListener('click', removeMarkedText);
  }
};

const removeMarkedText = event => {
  const mark = event.target;
  if (mark.tagName === 'MARK') {
    const textNode = document.createTextNode(mark.textContent);
    mark.replaceWith(textNode);
  }
};

// Add event listeners for when user selects text on any element
body.addEventListener("pointerup", highlightText);
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Comment: Nice answer! The remove function is not very fluid tho. Sometimes it removes all the selected elements instead of the one I clicked hover, sometimes needs double click to remove.

Comment: @RGS updated the answer to hopefully  make it more smoother